# How to vertically align 2 items in a flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to align 2 images horizontally, however, I want a 3rd item (string inside a paragraph) to align vertically underneath 1 of the images.

[image: Current layout]

The 3rd item (Week-by-Week Predictor) should go underneath the first image.

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox-item {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border: 3px yellow inset;
}

.flexbox-item-1 {
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-1"> <img src="junk\Dark Pink Morning 
  Routine Tutorial YouTube Thumbnail (1).png" alt=""> </div>

  <p class="flexbox-item-1">Week-by-Week Predictor</p>

  <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-2"> <img src="junk\Dark Pink Morning 
  Routine Tutorial YouTube Thumbnail (2).png" alt=""> <p>Season Predictor</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot put the paragraph inside the "flexbox-item flexbox-item-1" div otherwise it results as seen in the image on the right.
So I would like to align the text underneath the div.
Please can someone help me.

Comment: Wrap the first div and the p in another flex with direction column

Answer (score 2):

Give a try with display:grid.

```
.flexbox-container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 25% 25%;
 justify-content: center;
 gap:5%;   /* according to your need */
}
```

Remove or make the width 100% of '.flexbox-item'

```
.flexbox-item {
 width: 100%;
 }
```

Add order to the 3rd item

```
 p.flexbox-item-1 {order:1}
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="left-flex">
    <div class="flexbox-item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/800px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""> </div>

    <p class="">Week-by-Week Predictor</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flexbox-item"> <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/800px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt=""> <p>Season Predictor</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

And the updated CSS:

```
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flexbox-item {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  border: 3px yellow inset;
}

.left-flex{
  width: 50%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.right-flex{
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 80%;
}
```